# Trying to build a circuit to boost 5 V DC to 250 V DC with fairly low current output

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, boost

I am fairly inexperienced with electronics, but I am trying to build a 250 V DC supply from a 5V source. From research, I have run across charge pumps and boost converters. I tried using charge pumps, and the voltage output wasn't efficient. I ended up using a lot of capacitors and when I put my load on,it significantly dropped the output voltage.

I am now looking into IC boost converters. I ran into some, most notably [TPS40210](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps40210-q1.pdf). The data sheet says it can output 260V, but there are no such example circuits. I am wondering if there's a way that is typically preferred to achieve such boost. I am hoping to get a relatively small footprint if that's possible.

Comment: How much is "fairly low"?

Comment: Do you have a higher-voltage supply available.  That is: where does your 5V supply come from?  If your 5V supply comes from a higher supply voltage, that makes it easier to get your 250Vdc output.

Comment: What is you load? How many A/mA? Is the load static or does it vary? What exactly is a small footprint? You need to give us a little more information.

Comment: What current do you need at 250V?

Comment: The current required is around 3 uA or so. 
Well a small footprint just means that anything that can be fit in a pcb less than 5cm x 3cm. The load I believe varies.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting 260V from? The datasheet has multiple references to 260 mV as the reference voltage, but this has nothing to do with he output voltage limit.  There actually is no limit on the output voltage as far as I can tell, so long as you use components that have high enough ratings - namely the output capacitor, diode, and switching transistor.  All you need to do is divide the output voltage down to the reference voltage and get the compensation set up correctly.

However, for generating very high voltages, a voltage multiplier of some sort may be preferable.  However, this may also experience droop in the same manner as the charge pump circuit.

Comment: The poster is correct. Right on the devices description page it reads: TPS40210 ... Vin (Min) (V) 4.5 ... Vout (Max) (V) 260. Unless it is a typo. The datasheet states that the maximum feedback voltage is 260mV which probably corresponds to a maximum of a 260V signal on the divider input.

Comment: That is very odd.  The datasheet has no reference to the maximum output voltage.  There is no direct connection back to the controller, so I do not see why the controller would impose any limit on the output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [calculator and circuit](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-boost-calc/the-calculator).

It is quite simple and can be built using a microcontroller as the PWM generator. BUT if you need current beyond 50mA, the components start to see a lot of transient current surges which can quickly wreck capacitors and blow diodes/transistors if not spec'd right.